# How do I solve "Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in System.Net.Http.dll"?

Tags: c#, .net, formatexception

This is the method that executes whenever a WPF button is clicked:

```
private void Dial(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SendDataAsync(sender, e);
}

private async Task SendDataAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{   
    //this method does the actual dialing part
    var toSend = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "ClientID", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientID"] },
        { "PhoneNumber", numberToSend }
    };

    string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(toSend);

    var content = new StringContent(jsonString);

    content.Headers.Add("Content-type", "text/json");
    content.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/json");

    var response = await client.PostAsync("https://webhook.site/4788266d-9caf-4747-a3d2-09777b233435", content);

    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

}
```

I've tried commenting out either of the "content.headers.add" lines, but the error remained.

This is the full exception as shown in the output from debug:

> Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in System.Net.Http.dll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos)' comment at [Mar 23 at 9:55](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75821464/how-do-i-solve-exception-thrown-system-formatexception-in-system-net-http-dl#comment133745566_75821464):

> You can't have two content types. You can replace all this code with [PostAsJsonAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.postasjsonasync?view=net-8.0) eg `await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url,toSend);`